# How do I change the grid of a draggable element when it goes over a certain div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

So I am making something...here's my code so far

```
$('.draggableThing').draggable({grid:[20,20]});
```

When the element is dragged on top of a certain div, I want it to change the grid to [1,1]. So it is smooth while on this div but only moves on the [20,20] grid everywhere else. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. But let me know if anyone has a better solution because I don't really understand how JQuery works.

```
function makeDraggable()
{
    $('.draggableThing').draggable({
        grid:[20,20],
        drag:function(){
            if (
                $(this).position().top>$('.theDivToDragOn').position().top
                &&$(this).position().top<$(".theDivToDragOn").position().top+$(".theDivToDragOn").innerHeight()
                &&$(this).position().left>$('.theDivToDragOn').position().left
                &&$(this).position().left<$(".theDivToDragOn").position().left+$(".theDivToDragOn").innerWidth()
            ){
                $(this).toggleClass('draggableThing').toggleClass('smoothDraggable');
                $('.smoothDraggable').draggable({
                    grid:[1,1],
                    drag:function(){
                        if (
                            $(this).position().top<$('.theDivToDragOn').position().top
                            ||$(this).position().top>$(".theDivToDragOn").position().top+$(".theDivToDragOn").innerHeight()
                            ||$(this).position().left<$('.theDivToDragOn').position().left
                            ||$(this).position().left>$(".theDivToDragOn").position().left+$(".theDivToDragOn").innerWidth()
                        ){ 
                        $(this).toggleClass('draggableThing').toggleClass('smoothDraggable');
                        makeDraggable();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
}
```